# edge.create firing from like box in my website but not from facebook page itself

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have configured fb like box (likes my page) on my website. It works fine. Stores the details of the user in DB. But when a user actually actually goes to the facebook page and likes it, the edge.create wont fire. Please offer a foolproof way of storing the details of users who like my facebook page from anywhere (website like box/actual facebook page)

Comment: _“But when a user actually actually goes to the facebook page and likes it, the edge.create wont fire.”_ – well of course it doesn’t, because your event is on a completely different website. _“Please offer a foolproof way of storing the details of users who like my facebook page from anywhere”_ – why, what would want that information for anyway? You are not allowed to reward users for liking, contact them just because they liked your page or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to authorize users on your website with the `user_likes` permission. `user_likes` requires approval from Facebook, so it depends what you want to achieve. If you want to use it for like gating, you will not get it approved - like gating is not allowed anymore.

After authorizing, you can get the likes with /me/likes: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/likes

More information about user_likes: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-user_likes